# Usage of "do" with "get": you do get

Tags: word-usage

I just can't understand the role of *do* in the following statement:

> When you **do** get your study permit and have made your plans to travel,
>   please let us know.

Is it necessary to put it there?

I've heard about the usage of *do* for putting emphasis, but I think if this is the case for the above sentence, it should be used for *let*:

> please do let us know

and not for *get*.

Comment: Were there preceding sentences talking about the consequences of not having a study permit?  Sometimes the auxiliary _do_ can be used to emphasize a contrast with or opposition to what came before. Like "I hate most desserts, but I _do_ love pie."  In this case, the contrast could be to the situation of having no study permit that was just being discussed.

Answer (score 2):

It could be paraphrased as "when, *at long last*, you have received ...".

That is, when, after you have completed all the required forms, and have waited patiently for these forms to be processed, and the permit has arrived in the mail....

Or it could be paraphrased:

When your application for a permit is successful...

The nuanced meaning would depend on the statements made prior to the one in question.

Comment: You mean the "do" is there because the process of getting permit may take so long, something like "finally"?

Comment: it could mean *finally*, or it could mean "when your application results in your receipt of a permit". The meaning would depend on statements made *before* this statement.